# VB.net null reference exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, xpath, nullreferenceexception

I am working on a project to share playlists between users, I am using an XML document "playlist.xml".

The following is the code that is giving me the null reference exception

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function getList(ByVal listNick As String) As String

    Dim root As XmlNode = getDocument()
    Dim number As Double
    Dim n As XmlNodeList
    n = root.SelectNodes("//playlist")
    number = n.Count

    Dim found As Boolean = False
    'For Each node As XmlNode In n
    Dim the_list As String = root.SelectSingleNode("playlists/playlist[@name='" + listNick + "']").InnerXml
    Return the_list
    'n =   root.SelectSingleNode(“WebShop/Departments/Department[@name=’Hardware’]) 

    'Next

    If (Not found) Then
        'Return "Not found among: " + number.ToString + "\n" + "did find: " + n.Item(1).Value ---to test for errors
        Return "0"
    Else
        Return "[getList] if you read this, jamie has failed his logic somewhere."
    End If


End Function
```

and here is the stack trace:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Service.getList(String listNick) in C:\Users\jamie\Dropbox\UNIVERSITY\WebSite\App_Code\Service.vb:line 36 --line 11 on the code i posted

This is coursework for uni.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is either `root` or `n` is null.

Verify this by putting a break point on the following line:

```
Dim number As Double
```

When that break point is hit, then hover over `root` and see if is null or not.

If it is, then there is a null in `getDocument()`.

If not, then step past this line:

```
number = n.Count
```

Now, hover over `n` and if it is null or not.

If it is null, then this line:

```
n = root.SelectNodes("//playlist")
```

has a null reference issue.

---

> Note: Regardless of the reason above, learning how to debug your program is the key to finding `NullReferenceException`s and any other exceptions for that matter.

Comment: after stepping past root and n, both were contents of the xml document... however the_list remained nothing, i do not see why.

Comment: So when stepping through the code, which line does it throw the exception on?

Comment: when it returns i get the exception

Comment: You did not post the code that calls the web service method, where is that code?

Comment: i'm using the built in web client, it's a webpage on my browser that asks me for any parameters